# Excel: Unable to break a link to an external file

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook with links to external Excel-Add-In-files. Recently I migrated the files from old Excel 2003 to current Excel versions. The Workbook now is a `.xml`-file and the Excel-Add-In file is now a `.xlam`-file.

After changing the references in VBA and saving all files in the new format, I have a link left that still points to the old `.xla`-File.
I searched all vba codes, all worksheet-formulas and all name-references for any occurence of the old `.xla`-file without success.

I could neither update the link nor break the link. Any suggestions welcome! Thank You

Comment: Try file-> check for issues -> check compatibility.

Comment: Thank You Greg, that did not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I extracted the `.xlsm`-file-structure to a directory and searched the xml-contents for the old addin-filename. I found conditional formatting that used a formula and was not updated to the new `.xlam`-file but still referred to the old `.xla`-file.

So Excel does not update **all** links to a file: formulas in conditional formatting are not updated.

The solution was to change the formulas of the conditional formatting and the missing reference problem was gone.
So I think, this is more an exotic problem, as conitional formatting with formulas is not very common and a formula containing a function to an external file isn't either.